# Can linear combinations of real numbers with integer coefficients produce every real number?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Can there exist a finite set $S$ such that the set

$$S' = \{ \sum a_i \beta_i, a_i \in \mathbb Z, \beta_i \in S\}$$

Is the set of all real numbers?

If no, prove the same

Comment: Any such collection of linear combinations would be a countably infinite set, but the reals are uncountable

Comment: @RobBland Thanks, that solves it